# Custom MapReduce Hive not Java

Tags: c#, mapreduce, hive

is it possible to add mapper and/or reducer scripts written in something else than java to a hive query?

I would prefer c# if possible.

Cheers, 
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html).  While it won't be as efficient as using Java:

> The utility allows you to create and run Map/Reduce jobs with any
>   executable or script as the mapper and/or the reducer.

Comment: Am I right if I say I stream the c# code in the maper/reducer and call the mapper in hive?